# Unsupported URL error using Swift and opening custom URL scheme

Tags: swift, ios8, spotify

I'm working with the Spotify **iOS SDK**, and trying to relaunch my app after authenticating the user. Using a custom `URL` scheme, I'm able to have my app relaunched, but I'm getting an error in my callback function so I'm not receiving any session data for the user. The error is:

> Error Domain=NSURLError

Here's where I'm capturing the error and printing to console:

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {

    var authCallback: SPTAuthCallback = { (error: NSError!, session: SPTSession!) in
        if (error != nil) {
            println("there's an error \(error)")
            return

        }
     }
```

Here's the full text of the error message:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo=0x7f97931069a0
{NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f979140a610 "unsupported URL"}
```

FWIW, this same method seems to work fine in the Objective-C demo apps that Spotify provides, but I'm assuming I'm missing something in my Swift translation.

EDIT: Here's how it is in Obj-C. There's no error populated here.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {


SPTAuthCallback authCallback = ^(NSError *error, SPTSession *session) {
    // This is the callback that'll be triggered when auth is completed (or fails).
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"*** Auth error: %@", error);
        return;
    }
```